# Can Anyone Tell Me Why I Got This Unhandled Exception Error In Flutter?

Tags: flutter, unhandled-exception

Unhandled Exception: type '() => Widget' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Can you send your code?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The error is pretty self explanatory. You are putting a function that returns a widget where a string is expected. My guess is you use `()=>Text("text")` somewhere where you should just put `"text"`

Answer (score 1):

Taking Ivo's comment a little further, it's saying that you're calling a function that returns a widget where it's expecting a plain old string. There should be a line number specified, perhaps with a link you can click on. Wherever that is, look for the function that's returning a Widget and figure out what string you want to be using there.